# CMake project using gettext on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake, gettext, vcpkg

I have a CMake project that uses gettext, and have installed gettext on my machine through vcpkg. Running vcpkg install gettext:x64-windows gave me this message:

```
The package gettext:x86-windows provides CMake targets:

    find_package(unofficial-gettext CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE unofficial::gettext::libintl)
```

I added that to my CMakeLists.txt file, and when Visual Studio 2017 tries to generate the CMake cache from it, it says:

```
1> C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe  -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\Enno\CMakeBuilds\1f25c7de-1ae7-7131-9c5a-889a4e831935\install\x64-Debug"  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\Enno\source\repos\echeck" returned with exit code: 1
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "unofficial-gettext" with any of the following names:
    unofficial-gettextConfig.cmake
    unofficial-gettext-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "unofficial-gettext" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "unofficial-gettext_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "unofficial-gettext" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

The file exists as C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\share\unofficial-gettext\unofficial-gettext-config.cmake, though.

I've added this to my CMakeSettings_schema.json, but it made no difference:
"cmakeCommandArgs": "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",

I've never seen that `unofficial::gettext::libintl` syntax before, but since the failure already occurs in the find_package command, I assume that's unrelated for now. What is my mistake here?

Comment: `unofficial::gettext::libintl` just means that the `libintl` is part of the `unofficial::gettext::` namespace. You'll find similar names in some other libs as well, e.g. `Qt5::Widgets` or `boost::unit_test_framework`. This shouldn't change anything for you though. Not sure if your toolchain file is supposed to contain this info, but does adding the prefix path change anything: `-D 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows'`?

Comment: That made the find_package error go away, but now I see this instead:
    1> -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Enno/source/repos/echeck
    1> Starting CMake target info extraction ...
    1> CMake server connection made.
    1> Target info extraction done.
    1> Configuration failed.

Answer (score 1):

Currently vcpkg uses a vcpkg owned CMakeLists.txt to build parts of gettext (only libintl). Since it is a vcpkg owned cmake build script vcpkg is free to export targets one of them being `unofficial::gettext::libintl` to correctly link against libintl in other vcpkg owned cmake builds.
In the future those `unofficial` namespaced targets will be removed since the build will be changed to the native build of the port (meson/autotools/make) [For gettext this will be done in PR https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/11776]. Thus you should not rely on any of them being available since it will lock your built to vcpkg.
For libintl CMake has a `FindIntl.cmake` which should be used instead. If `find_packe(Intl)` is not working correctly please open up an issue in vcpkg

Comment: Thanks, that was very informative! I realized that FindIntl wasn't working, so when vcpkg suggested using a different package name (unofficial-gettext), I tried that instead, and that's how I came to post this question. I will open an issue with vcpkg later today, and until then, make do without i18n support for Windows users.

Comment: i18n is `FindICU.cmake` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindICU.html

Comment: It seems that the FindIntl.cmake that's shipping with vcpkg doesn't look for the correct library name. `find_library(Intl_LIBRARY "intl" DOC "libintl libraries (if not in the C library)")` doesn't find the library, because it is called `libintl`. I can work around this by adding `find_library(Intl_LIBRARY NAMES libintl intl)` before the `find_package(Intl)` command. I opened an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/14548 - thanks for your help!